# ProgressDialog is not showing when .3gp file converting to a .zip

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-videoview

I am working on Android app.

I need to show a progress dialog box when I click on button.

In that button I am converting video file to .zip file and calculating that file size.
In this process I need to show a ProgressDialog, but it is not showing.

Screen get struck while calculating and after calculation it shows ProgressDialog and then screen navigating to the next screen.

**My Code:**

```
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    MediaCheck.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(MediaCheck.this, "",
                                    "Checking the video compatability. Please wait", true);
                        }
                    });
                    video_Path= makeZip(video_Path);
                    if (video_Path.equalsIgnoreCase("File size is too large")) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Large video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        return;
                    }
pd.dismiss();       
// Doing screen navigation here.
        }
    });
```

**Code to make a zip and know the size**

```
private static String makeZip(String videoPath) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    String[] videoFileName = videoPath.split("/");
    File directory = null;
    try {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context_this);
        // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(directory
                + "/IRCMS_Video.zip");
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        ze = new ZipEntry(videoFileName[5]);
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(videoPath);

        int len;

        while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        File videoZip = new File(directory + "/IRCMS_Video.zip");
        videoLength = videoZip.length() / (1024 * 1024);
        if (videoLength > 3)
            return "File size is too large";
        in.close();
        zos.closeEntry();

        // remember close it
        zos.close();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return directory.toString() + "/IRCMS_Video.zip";

}
}
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then you should try `ASYNCTASK` to easily perform your operation and reduce the complexity of using threads

```
private class Converter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> { //Converter is class name
     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         //THIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED AFTER ONPREEXECUTE
         //YOUR NETWORK OPERATION HERE
         return null;
     }

     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         //THIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED FIRST
         //DO OPERATION LIKE SHOWING PROGRESS DIALOG PRIOR TO BEGIN NETWORK OPERATION
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         super.onPostExecute();
         //TNIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED AT LAST AFTER DOINBACKGROUND
         //DO OPERATION LIKE UPDATING UI HERE
     }
 }
```

Comment: I wrote ProgressDialog.show(MediaCheck.this, "", ...) please see it once.
Even I tried that, but did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing calculation on UI thread therfore it hangs your app. Do calculation on background thread. You can resolve this by-

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(MediaCheck.this, "",
                        "Checking the video compatability. Please wait", true);
                Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        video_Path= makeZip(video_Path);

                        MediaCheck.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                        {
                            public void run() 
                            {

                                if (video_Path.equalsIgnoreCase("File size is too large")) {
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Large video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                    pd.dismiss();  
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                background.start();
                // Doing screen navigation here.
            }
        });
```

Comment: Gaurav Berry has appropriate answer. User2085985, never do long lasting operations in UI thread, because you will stuck your app and trigger ANR.